# i want to make ssh sevice always ON

Tags: ssh

i need to run $sudo service ssh start every time i startup my ssh service from my client to allow my master device run ssh username@clint_ip otherwise  i receive messages sys ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.104 port 22: Connection refused, I tried to change the port number to 2222 but didn't work also

Comment: what version of ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS (Xenial Xerus)
and my client is ubuntu mate 16.04

Comment: `systemctl reenable sshd.service` or maybe its `systemctl reenable openssh-server.service` ?

Comment: do i need to go to a certain directory?  i got this message when i run the both code you gave me sir " Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory "

Comment: Thanks, Mr @j-money i solved the issued by using the command $sudo raspi-config
 and click interfacing options,  Then I enable the ssh, Then reboot the device